# Emit event from js inside Livewire component that has video cause "Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node' error

Tags: laravel, html5-video, video.js, laravel-livewire

I have one component has video using videojs library to load it . In this component I emit event after 3 seconds to mark this vides as watched using this javascript code

```
 var player = videojs('yt-video')
        player.on('timeupdate', function() {        
            if(this.currentTime() > 3 ) {
                Livewire.emit('VideoViewed')
                this.off('timeupdate')
            }
        })
```

Then I listen to this event inside the class and I do DB update..

This works fine except one issue .

After the component trigger the event , the video continue to play but it show the play button even the video is playing  and remove all video controls also it through this error in the console.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.
    at t.<anonymous> (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.min.js:19:51700)
    at t.<anonymous> (https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.min.js:12:25973)
    at https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.min.js:12:25749
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

resolved using  wire:ignore directive in parent div for the video